# WIll powered rails make powered minecarts faster?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Will placing powered rails to make powered minecarts go faster? I want to make trains with powered minecarts that push normal ones and ones with chests. I saw that normal minecarts go slower on powered rails, but is it the same with powered minecarts (with furnaces)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence is not entirely correct : minecarts go slower on **unactivated** powered rails.

The purpose of powered rails is to increase or decrease the speed of minecarts ; to increase their speed, they must be activated by redstone.

Powered minecarts will *not* activate powered rails, and will not accelerate on them either.